# Caesar Code in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a caesar code program which decodes and encodes code.
It will take in a file and return a decoded or encode file.

Here is what I have written:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cc
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    System.out.println("Welcome to CaesarCipher");
    System.out.print("Enter 1 to encipher, or 2 to decipher (-1 to exit) ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What non-negative shift should I use? ");
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan1.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is the input file name? ");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String file = scan2.nextLine();
    System.out.print("What is the output file name? ");
    Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String savefile = scan3.nextLine();
    if (answer == 1)
    {
      encode(file, savefile, i);
    } else if ( answer == 2)
    {
      decode(file, savefile, i);
    } else if ( answer == -1)
    {
      System.out.println("See you later, aligator!");;
    }
    System.out.println("DONE!");
  }

  public static void encode(String file, String savefile, int i) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    File f2 = new File(savefile);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f2, "UTF-8");

    i = i % 26 + 26;
    File f = new File(file);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));
      StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
      for (char y : file.toCharArray())
      {
        if (Character.isLetter(y))
        {
          if (Character.isUpperCase(y))
          {
          encoded.append((char) ('A' + (y - 'A' + y) % 26 ));
          } else
          {
            encoded.append((char) ('a' + (y - 'a' + y) % 26 ));
          }
         } else
         {
          encoded.append(y);
         }
        writer.print(encoded.toString());
    }
    writer.close();
  }

  public static void decode(String file, String savefile, int i) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    encode(file, savefile, 26-i);
  }
}
```

The problem is however, that the output file is always empty. 
What is wrong with my code?

**[EDIT]**

Hi, I added the `writer.close();` but I still have a problem.

When I input **`cows are mowing everyone is happy`** in the input file with a shift of 2 it gives me the output

```
**hhbhbphbpphbppvhbppv.hbppv.fhbppv.fnhbppv.fnf**
```

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Call `writer.close()` after `writer.print()`

Comment: @BoDidely  
Hi, I edited my question. Could you please give a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Try not to move the goal posts when asking a question. If you keep changing what the question is, answers become irrelevant and the way the site works falls apart a bit.

Comment: Can you tell us what the name of the input file was?

Comment: @tnw I apologize for any inconveniences caused.

Comment: @JohnSmith Not a problem... if you have an additional issue after resolving the original one you're of course welcome to just post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your PrintWriter stream.

```
writer.close();
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Could you please give a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith is that the expected output of your Caesar Shift? If you need validation use the traditional pen and paper method.

Comment: @JohnSmith if I answered your initial question please click the opaque checkmark next to the answer for other developers on the forum.

Answer (score 1):

First, put the write statement after the end of the encoding loop:

```
for (char y : ...
    ...
} 
writer.print(encoded.toString());
writer.close();
```

Second, you cannot use the file name (!) to access file data:

```
file.toCharArray()
```

returns a char arrac containing the characters of the input file name. Read the file one by one:

```
File f = new File(file);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
int y;
while( (y = is.read()) != -1 ){
    // ...
}
```